# Clipboard and class issue when running AppleScript "do shell script..."

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, copy-paste

I have a simple bash command that I have tried to envoke from AppleScript but it makes a strange unicode substitution.

Example content of the clipboard:

> # 6C (d1/s2): F 11-12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y)

The terminal command:

```
$ pbpaste | gsed 's/\x2D/\xE2\x96\xB8/g' | pbcopy
```

changes "-" to "▸" when it finds it on the clipboard

```
-
HYPHEN-MINUS
Unicode: U+002D, UTF-8: 2D

▸
BLACK RIGHT-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE
Unicode: U+25B8, UTF-8: E2 96 B8
```

**Output from clipboard is good:**

> # 6C (d1/s2): F 11▸12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y)

The AppleScript as I wrote it:

```
do shell script "pbpaste | gsed 's/\\x2D/\\xE2\\x96\\xB8/g' | pbcopy"
```

**Output from clipboard is incorrect:**

> # 6C (d1/s2): F 11‚ñ∏12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y)

I tried messing around with something like this in AppleScript

```
set the clipboard to «class ktxt» of ((the clipboard as text) as record)
```

I also took a peek at the contents of the clipboard after copying the text from a website using this command in terminal:

```
$ osascript -e "the clipboard as record"
osascript -e "the clipboard as record"
«class HTML»:«data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», «class utf8»:# 6C (d1/s2): F 11-12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y), «class ut16»:# 6C (d1/s2): F 11-12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y), string:# 6C (d1/s2): F 11-12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y), Unicode text:# 6C (d1/s2): F 11-12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y)
```

The "same" text after it has been run through the terminal command and pasted into a Stickies note:

```
$ osascript -e "the clipboard as record"
osascript -e "the clipboard as record"
«class RTF »:«data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», «class utf8»:# 6C (d1/s2): F 11▸12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y), «class ut16»:# 6C (d1/s2): F 11▸12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y), string:# 6C (d1/s2): F 11, Unicode text:# 6C (d1/s2): F 11▸12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y)
```

Just extra info. The characters that were substituted for what I want have this unicode info

```
ñ
LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE
Unicode: U+00F1, UTF-8: C3 B1
∏
N-ARY PRODUCT
Unicode: U+220F, UTF-8: E2 88 8F
```

EDIT:
It seems that piping the results to `pbcopy`, while working in terminal, was an issue when called from AppleScript.

I changed the AppleScript to:

```
do shell script "pbpaste | gsed 's/\\x2D/\\xE2\\x96\\xB8/g'; pbcopy"
```

?? The results show up inside the AppleScript Result window, but this clears the Clipboard... Does anyone know why AppleScript is clearing the clipboard when using `pbcopy` in a `do shell script` command?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to replace the `-` with `▸`, then here is how I'd do it:

Note that in the *example* **AppleScript** *code* the first and last lines of it are for testing to actually set the expected content of the clipboard to work with, obviously they are not needed in the working *code*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set the clipboard to "# 6C (d1/s2): F 11-12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y)"

set cbText to (the clipboard as text)

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "-"
set cbText to text items of cbText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "▸"
set cbText to cbText as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

set the clipboard to cbText

return (the clipboard)
```

> Result:
> # 6C (d1/s2): F 11▸12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y)

---

On a side note, the issue appears to be with the `| pbcopy` segment of the *command*.

Here is another workaround:

Assuming `# 6C (d1/s2): F 11-12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y)` is what's on the clipboard, then:

```
set the clipboard to ¬
    (do shell script "pbpaste | gsed 's/\\x2D/\\xE2\\x96\\xB8/g'")
```

Results in `# 6C (d1/s2): F 11▸12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y)` being on the clipboard.

Comment: That is one way to do it. I was trying to understand why the `do shell script` part of my AppleScript was failing. I didn't figure out why but did find how to circumvent the issue. Where is the best place to add this circumvention?

Comment: @John, RE: "I was trying to understand why the do shell script part of my AppleScript was failing." -- The issues appears to be in the `| pbcopy` segment of the _command_, in that the output of `pbpaste | gsed 's/\\x2D/\\xE2\\x96\\xB8/g'` is correctly `# 6C (d1/s2): F 11▸12 100 Fly (1:12.95Y)` in the `do shell script` _command_, buts gets mangled being _piped_ to `pbcopy` See updated answer for another method example.

Comment: Yeah, it's how Script Editor is interpreting that content.  I tried using `pbpaste` with the flag `-Prefer {rtf}` but it made no difference. It think there is a missing command that helps Apple Script interpret the kind of text its getting back from the shell script before it puts in back on the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

While @user3439894 did present a workaround solution I did find the answer to the pbcopy issue with help from a user on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/applescript/comments/lpzsv8/do_shell_script_and_pbcopy/godz7tz/). Hope this provides help at some point in the future.

> Piping to pbcopy is the correct approach. Since `do shell script` does not run your login shell (see Technical Note TN2065), you have to
> supply the locale as an environment variable. For Canadian English:

```
do shell script "pbpaste | gsed 's/\\x2D/\\xE2\\x96\\xB8/g'| LANG=en_CA.UTF-8 pbcopy"
```

> or
>
> For current system language:

```
do shell script "pbpaste | gsed 's/\\x2D/\\xE2\\x96\\xB8/g'| LANG=" & user locale of (system info) & ".UTF-8 pbcopy"
```

> This caused me quite a lot of confusion when I was making some
> clipboard-modifying handlers. And for reference, I found that you're
> much better off using pbpaste/pbcopy than using the built-in commands
> from StandardAdditions as these have their own quirks.

So making a small adjustment to their solution results in:

```
do shell script "pbpaste | gsed 's/\\x2D/\\xE2\\x96\\xB8/g' | LANG=en_US.UTF-8 pbcopy"
```